# Error in veins_inet: Mobility position is not a finite number after initialize (x=nan, y=nan, z= nan)

Tags: omnet++, veins

I'm very beginner to veins. I'm building a network in which ther is a standard host and a vehicle communoicate to each other via AccessPoint. I've successful done this simulation with wirelessHost and standard host. but when I used veins_inet to simulate adhocHost as a vehicle I get this error

"[image: error]"

**My source code is following.**

############################# .ned ############################

```
network ScenarioFOG
{
    submodules:
        radioMedium: Ieee80211ScalarRadioMedium {
            @display("p=29,130");
        }
        manager: VeinsInetManager;
        
        configurator: IPv4NetworkConfigurator {
            parameters:
                assignDisjunctSubnetAddresses = false;
                @display("p=36,83");
        }
        
        vNode[0]: Car;
        
        sNode: StandardHost {
            @display("p=260,61");
        }
        AP: AccessPoint {
            @display("p=197,79");
        }

    connections allowunconnected:
        sNode.ethg++ <--> Eth100M <--> AP.ethg++; 
}
```

############################# .ini ############################

```
[General]
network = ScenarioFOG
sim-time-limit = 60s
debug-on-errors = true
cmdenv-express-mode = true
image-path = ../../../../images

# UDPBasicApp
ScenarioFOG.*Node[*].numUdpApps = 1
ScenarioFOG.*Node[*].udpApp[0].typename = "UDPBasicApp"
ScenarioFOG.vNode[*].udpApp[0].destAddresses = "224.0.0.1"
ScenarioFOG.vNode[*].udpApp[0].multicastInterface = "wlan0"
ScenarioFOG.vNode[*].udpApp[0].joinLocalMulticastGroups = true
ScenarioFOG.sNode[*].udpApp[0].localPort = 9001
ScenarioFOG.vNode[*].udpApp[0].destPort = 9001
ScenarioFOG.vNode[*].udpApp[0].destAddresses = "sNode"
ScenarioFOG.sNode[*].udpApp[0].destAddresses = "vNode"
ScenarioFOG.vNode[*].udpApp[0].messageLength = 100B
ScenarioFOG.vNode[*].udpApp[0].startTime = uniform(0s, 5s)
ScenarioFOG.vNode[*].udpApp[0].sendInterval = 5s

# Ieee80211MgmtAdhoc
ScenarioFOG.vNode[*].wlan[0].mgmtType = "Ieee80211MgmtAdhoc"
ScenarioFOG.vNode[*].wlan[0].bitrate = 6Mbps
ScenarioFOG.vNode[*].wlan[0].radio.transmitter.power = 2mW

# HostAutoConfigurator
ScenarioFOG.vNode[*].ac_wlan.interfaces = "wlan0"
ScenarioFOG.vNode[*].ac_wlan.mcastGroups = "224.0.0.1"

# VeinsInetMobility
**.vNode[*].mobilityType = "VeinsInetMobility" 
**.vNode[*].mobility.constraintAreaMinX = 0m
**.vNode[*].mobility.constraintAreaMinY = 0m
**.vNode[*].mobility.constraintAreaMinZ = 0m
**.vNode[*].mobility.constraintAreaMaxX = 1000m
**.vNode[*].mobility.constraintAreaMaxY = 1000m
**.vNode[*].mobility.constraintAreaMaxZ = 0m
**.vNode[*].mobility.initFromDisplayString = false
**.vNode[*].mobility.initialX = 200m
**.vNode[*].mobility.initialY = 100m
**.vNode[*].mobility.initialZ = 0m


# VeinsInetManager
ScenarioFOG.manager.updateInterval = 0.1s
ScenarioFOG.manager.host = "localhost"
ScenarioFOg.manager.port = 9999
ScenarioFOG.manager.autoShutdown = true
**.manager.launchConfig = xmldoc("square.launchd.xml")
ScenarioFOG.manager.moduleType = "org.car2x.veins.subprojects.veins_inet.example.Car"

**.vector-recording = true
```

Comment: My recommendation would be to start from the `veins_inet` example and, if this works on your machine, start modifying it to suit your use case.

Comment: I've already modified in this same method, but unfortunately this error exists, till now.